# Tomcat couldn't see servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web

When I run my webapp with Netbeans it works perfectly, but I can't everytime for using this webapp open netbeans and run it. I download netbeans with apache tomcat, and with netbeans it works fine. But then when i need to run tomcat separately, i have problems. I run it, open webb app manager, deploy war file of my project. Then i try to run it, so i have first index.jsp page without problem, then it should do smth in servlet pages, this things doesn't work. So tomcat couldn't see servlet. I know that problem may be because I don't have web.xml file, it wouldn't generated automatically, because of mine is servlet 3.0 or smth, so i have this annotations `@WebServlet(name = "zakaz", urlPatterns = {"/zakaz"})` but it still doesn't work. I can't understand why, do you have any ideas?
I get null pointer exception in Tomcat

Comment: which version of tomcat you are using. you must sure that you are using tomcat 7 and above as you are using annotations of web 3.

Comment: yes, i know, i  work with Tomcat 7, i've also tried 8

Comment: figure out the "or smth" whatever that means (if you can't even be bothered to type full words, why would anyone be bothered to try to help you?).

Comment: If *things doesn't work*, I suppose you get errors in tomcat logs and in your browser. What are these errors, 404, or anything else ?

Comment: Sorry, it's because of my bad english. Things doesn't work means without any errors, it just doesn't show anything. It should do searching, and i get empty results. But with Netbeans everything works in Tomcat i get null pointer exception error

Comment: smth means searching:) It should get searching results

Comment: Please show a stacktrace if you get an NPE.

Comment: Thanks everyone, i solve problem with changing server.xml file:)